# What is the meaning of int "f" in this function in C?

Tags: c, integer

```
int f( int i ) {
    printf("called f\n"); 
    if (i < 0) return -i; 
    else
    return 3 * i;
 }
```

I just want to know what int "f" means.

Comment: `f` is the name of the function and `int` is what it returns

Comment: Please get a beginners book about C. Any book. class or online tutorial that haven't taught you this should be thrown away.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `int f(int i)` means :

1. The first "int" is the type of the result returned by the function, aka -i or 3 * i with a type of "integer".
2. "f" is the name of the function. It could be whatever you want, for example "function".

Answer (score 2):

It is just the name of the function that was declared.
In this case it is a function that returns an integer.
We could declare the same one with a different name:

```
int name() {
    return (1 + 2);
}
```

The function that you provided is most likely used in the `main()` function, like this:

```
int main(){
    int x = 2;
    int output = f( x );
    printf("%d", output);
    return 0;
}
```